# Flutter map_view not showing markers

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter, dart-pub

I'm Using [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) to display google map on flutter app. The map is displaying.The problem is that,markers are not showing here is the code.

```
_openGooleMap() {
       mapView.addMarker(new Marker("1", "George", -6.7244448, 34.8536052, color: Colors.red)); //Doesn't work
       mapView.onMapTapped.listen((location) => print("Touched location $location")); // Works
       mapView.show(                                                                  // Works
         new MapOptions(
         showUserLocation: true,
        title: "MAP",
        initialCameraPosition:
            new CameraPosition(new Location(-6.7244448, 34.8536052), 6.0)),
    toolbarActions: <ToolbarAction>[new ToolbarAction("X", 1)]);
mapView.onToolbarAction.listen((id) {
  if (id == 1) {
    mapView.dismiss();
  }
});
```

}

What I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Managed to figure it out.. The Issue is that, I was setting the markers before the map initialization is completed.

```
 mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
  mapView.setMarkers(_markers);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until map load. set a listener.

mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
  mapView.setMarkers(_markers);
});

I found a simple example of a marker [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-with-google-map.html).